# How do instruct a cell to display a minimum value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I currently have the following formula in a cell:-

> =CEILING(E9*0.85, 1.25)

I would like the cell containing this formula to display a value no less than 20 but only when the value of E9 causes this. For any value of E9 which results in a computed value of 20 or above, I would like the cell to 'behave' normally.

How can I go about doing this?

I have tried using the '=IF', '=MIN' and '=MAX' formulas but they all yield errors and I have no experience in using multiple functions in a single cell.

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=max(CEILING(E9*0.85, 1.25),20)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
=IF(E9>19,CEILING(E9*0.85, 1.25),E9)
```

Comment: if (CEILING(E9*0.85, 1.25) > 19)  Also, not >19, but >=20.  The function does not necessarily return integers.